# Android Spinner does not display dropdown list when tapped

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a custom popup that I created in XML and in that popup there is a spinner that is supposed to have a dropdown list when tapped. The list is dynamically populated by an arraylist. When I tap the spinner in the app, it does not show the list at all and the tap basically does nothing but just highlight the spinner bar.

However, if I populate the spinner from a pre-created strings.xml array, it works just fine. Problem is that I need the list to dynamically change and I cannot do that with a pre-created array.

I have poured through pages and pages of other stackoverflow posts that talk about a similar issues and have essentially tried every suggestion that I've come across but no luck. I have also followed many different tutorials on how to properly create spinners and each time the same thing happens.

Here is the XML for the custom popup and the java activity code used to initialize the spinner.

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#474747"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Enter Current Floor #"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:onClick="goClicked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="#14B5DB"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity code:

```
Dialog myDialog;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDialog = new Dialog(this);

        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custompopup);

        addItemsOnSpinner();

}

public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) 
        myDialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> . 
        (myDialog.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dropdown.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

There are no error messages or anything, just does not display the list when the spinner is tapped. Sorry for the poor formatting, this is basically my first time posting code here. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to solve this for a while now and it doesn't seem like I can find a solution to my problem.

Comment: why are you putting your spinner inside extra linear layout it is unnecessary.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!